# Facebook login only works when hosts is set to localhost?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-login, hosts, openshift

Unfortunately I keep getting this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

Login works however when my `/etc/hosts` file is set to: `127.0.0.1 [mysite].rhcloud.com`, it only fails when I view the actual `[mysite].rhcloud.com`.

I am running the exact same application (on a different server) locally as the one I'm running on rhcloud. Specifically the local<->remote web-application directories are synced.

#### URL information

When attempting login remotely the URL looks like this; and fails with aforementioned error:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?scope=user_photos%2Cfriends_photos&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F[mypublicipaddress]%2Fuser%2Flogin&response_type=code&client_id=[hidden]

Whereas attempting to login locally the URL looks like this; and works:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=[hidden]&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2F[hidden].rhcloud.com%2Fuser%2Flogin&response_type=code&perms=user_photos%2Cfriends_photos&fbconnect=1

Comment: Can't vote to close because of the bounty - but see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191

Comment: @lgy: This isn't a duplicate, I had read the answers to that question but none have helped me overcome this error.

Comment: Can you confirm that your application's URL on Facebook is not set to localhost and your hosts file doesn't contain any urls?And what do you mean by "when attempting login remotely" vs "locally"?

Comment: The URL on facebook is set to `http://[mysite].rhcloud.com`, my hosts file contains `127.0.0.1 [mysite].rhcloud.com`. Logging in locally refers to logging in with that `/etc/hosts` line, whilst logging in remotely refers logging in without that line set.

Comment: redirect_uri is controlled in your app settings. Is redirect_uri URL found in Canvas/Pagetab/IOS/Android settings?

Answer (score 1):

OK, you seem to be doing this right, but there's one thing that sometimes trips people up, do both your `redirect_uri` and 'Website URL' field have a trailing '/'?

In particular, if the `redirect_uri` doesn't have the trailing '/' (or a filename, etc) after the domain name it doesn't always work

Comment: Double checked, it has no trailing `/`. Adding one explicitly makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

did you set your canvas URL/secure canvas URL in facebook app configuration. IF so, retry after removing them. Or try after making sure canvas URL should be correct.

Comment: Only set my "Website with Facebook login"

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The trailing `/` matters. Just check your these fields, and add that trailing `/` if it's not there.

But, to be honest, this is the first time I've seen something like this. Usually, we see `Facebook` logins failing on a local environment, but working just fine in production.

Comment: Double checked, it has no trailing `/`. Adding one explicitly makes no difference.

Comment: "Usually, we see Facebook logins failing on a local environment, but working just fine in production." I would not push to production something that is not working on local ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome exactly the same problem by accessing my facebook developer application account and changing the domain from localhost to the url of my application